# Change HTML element class name based on media query / when printing

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML using [Skeleton CSS](http://getskeleton.com):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="three columns"> 
        ...
      </section>
      <section id="content" class="nine columns">
        ...
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to modify the CSS such that when printing a page, the `three columns` section is hidden and the `nine columns` section spans the entire width.

The former can be done with a media query setting `display` to `none`.

How do I change the `content` section class from `nine columns` to `twelve columns` so that the content area will print using the entire width of a page? Or perhaps there's a better way when using Skeleton CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way would be overriding the width defined in .nine class, something like this.

```
@media print {
    .nine.columns {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```